# Create loops and parsing XML nodes value for Selenium tests

Tags: c#, xml, selenium

I am trying to write a test function in C# that read data from an XML file and parse into Selenium testing methods , the XML code is like:

```
<home>
   <ask_frame>
       <button>
      <id>Object ID<id>
      <xpath>Object XPath<xpath>
       <textbox>
      <id>Object ID<id>
      <xpath>Object XPath<xpath>
   </ask_frame>
   <search_frame>
      <id>Object ID<id>
      <xpath>Object XPath<xpath>
   </search_frame>
<home>
```

I am trying to create a loop that read the id and xpath value from these nodes and parse them into an method for searching a webpage element by id and xpath. My initial attempt was:

**Code updated**

```
         public void CheckIdTest()
    {
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(baseURL + "FlightSearch");
        XmlDocument xd = new XmlDocument();
        xd.Load(@"C:\XMLFile1.xml");
        XmlNodeList mainlist = xd.SelectNodes("//home/*");
        XmlNode mainroot = mainlist[0];

        foreach (XmlNode xnode in mainroot)
        {
            string objID = xnode.SelectSingleNode("id").InnerText;
            string objXPath = xnode.SelectSingleNode("XPath").InnerText;
            objID = objID.Trim();
            objXPath = objXPath.Trim();
            String checkValue = "ObjID value is: " + objID + Environment.NewLine+ "ObjXPath value is: " + objXPath;
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\checkvalue.txt", checkValue);
            objectCheck(objXPath, objID);
        }   
    }
```

I have put a String and checked that correct values for ObjID and ObjXPath have been achieved, but this loop also went only twice (checked 2 nodes in first branch). How could I make it runs through every node in my XML?

Any suggestions and explanations to the code will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically these two lines are using incorrect XPath :

```
XmlNodeList idlist = xd.SelectNodes("id");
XmlNodeList xpathlist = xd.SelectNodes("XPath");
```

`<id>` and `<xpath>` nodes aren't located directly at the root level, so you can't access it just like above. Besides, xpath is case-sensitive so you should've used "xpath" instead of "XPath". Try to fix it like this :

```
XmlNodeList idlist = xd.SelectNodes("//id");
XmlNodeList xpathlist = xd.SelectNodes("//xpath");
```

or more verbose :

```
XmlNodeList idlist = xd.SelectNodes("home/*/id");
XmlNodeList xpathlist = xd.SelectNodes("home/*/xpath");
```

**UPDATE :**

Responding to your comment about looping problem, I think you want to change it like this :

```
foreach (XmlNode xnode in mainroot.ChildNodes)
{
    string objID = xnode.SelectSingleNode("id").InnerText;
    string objXPath = pathroot.SelectSingleNode("xpath").InnerText;
    objectCheck(objID, objXPath);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the error is now solved by using the more verbose method. However according to the output text file , the loop itself seems only ran once..how shall i change the code if i want objectcjeck() to be executed for all nodes in the XML?

Comment: loop should run twice fine, but you're executing the same command (your code doesn't use `xnode` variable set in each loop iteration)

Comment: Okay, this is my first time using XML loops and I am getting bit confused now ,could you suggest me how shall i solve this problem? @har07

Comment: the loop has ran twice but only for the first XML element,is it because of "XmlNode mainroot = mainlist[0]" is only returning first element of array? @har07

Comment: Open new question for this problem. You have different XML markup and different C# codes now.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you are trying to use an object that is null i.e not instantiated.

Put in a breakpoint at the line

```
XmlDocument xd = new XmlDocument();
```

and step through line by line till you find where the nothing.null reference is.
It should not take long to find out what the problem is.

Comment: Thanks for answering, i wonder is there any syntax/technical error with the entire loop code i tried to run?